# Python locate specific data in string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split, coordinates

I'm receiving a string from a camera containing 'detailinfo,X,Y,angle, and not important'.
The string looks like this:**DET4 1 X:34.82 Y:70.28 VINKEL:244.33 LUTANDE:0**. VINKEL=angle.
Now I need to take the X,Y,angle data out of it, to send it to the robot.
The way i've done it is as follows,

```
CamX=received[9:15]
CamY=received[17:23]
Rotation=received[30:36]
```

The problem is that the "info" in X,Y,angle, can be in 3-digits, or 2 digits. So right now if i'm getting a 3-digit X value, the Y-value will be false. Is there any other way to locate and read the values of X,Y, angle?

Whole program:

```
#RECEIVING DATA FROM CAMERA#
import socket
import time
host= "192.168.1.10"
port= 3000

print("start");
S = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
S.connect((host,port))
received = str(S.recv(1024), "utf-8")
print(received);
S.close()

#CONVERTING DATA TO X,Y COORDINATES#

CamX=received[9:15]      
CamY=received[17:23]     

CamX=float(CamX)/100
CamY=float(CamY)/100
CamPos= '('+str(CamX) +','+str(CamY)+',0.2,0.01,3.14,0.01)'

print('X:', CamX)
print('Y:', CamY)
print(CamPos)


#SENDING DATA TO ROBOT#
host2="192.168.1.5"
port2= 30000
print("start");
SR = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
SR.bind((host2,port2))
SR.listen(5)
conn, addr=SR.accept()
print("Connected by ",addr)
conn.send(CamPos.encode('utf-8'))
print('Coordinates sent to robot')
```

Comment: Split the string into an array using space as the delimiter, then use substrings like `array[0][7:]`. Or better yet, use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not extremely robust. Anyway, try:

```
received = 'DET4 1 X:34.82 Y:70.28 VINKEL:244.33 LUTANDE:0'
lst = received.split()
print(lst)
x = float(lst[2].split(':')[1])
y = float(lst[3].split(':')[1])
print('x:', x, 'y:', y)
```

The first split uses default argument -- space, or tab, or newline.

The other code assumes that the `received` has the same form, so the position of the information is the same in the list. The second split by colon separates the X or Y identifier. The `[1]` after means you want the second part -- the number. And the `float()` converts it to the real number.

Answer (score 1):

As @rr said, regex is probably more reliable. You should start [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html). Something like that would work:

```
import re
input = 'DET4 1 X:34.82 Y:70.28 VINKEL:244.33 LUTANDE:0.'

try:
    cam_x = re.search(r'\sX:(?P<cam_x>\d+\.\d+)\s', input).group('cam_x')
    cam_y = re.search(r'\sY:(?P<cam_y>\d+\.\d+)\s', input).group('cam_y')
    rotation = re.search(r'\sVINKEL:(?P<rotation>\d+\.\d+)\s', input).group('rotation')
    print cam_x, cam_y, rotation
except AttributeError:
    print 'Unexpected formatting of the input.'
```

Basically these regexes match:

- \d = the digits
- separated by a \. = dot (like 32.45)
- following "X:" (or "Y:", or "VINKEL:")
- and surrounded by \s = whitespaces.

Comment: I might add that I am completely new to coding and python and have no idea how your code works, I've managed to do something myself, in a much more "noob" way (i guess)`r='DET4 1 X:134.812 Y:170.028 VINKEL:124.033 LUTANDE:0'
r=r.replace(r[0:9],'')
r=r.replace('Y:','')
r=r.replace('VINKEL:','')
r=r.replace('LUTANDE:0','')
r=r.replace(' ',',')
r=r.split(',')

camX=r[0]
camY=r[1]
camV=r[2]
print('R:',r)

print('X:',camX)
print('Y:',camY)
print('Vinkel:',camV)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
values = [(a[0],a[1]) for a in [ x.split(':') for x in text[7:].split()] if  a[0] == 'X' or [0] == 'Y' ]

print values
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers @SébastienDeprez, @andmart, @pepr

I'm completely new to coding and python, but I think I've managed to solve this on my own, maybe not as fancy as your codes, but it should do the work right?

```
r='DET4 1 X:134.812 Y:170.028 VINKEL:124.033 LUTANDE:0'
r=r.replace(r[0:9],'')
r=r.replace('Y:','')
r=r.replace('VINKEL:','')
r=r.replace('LUTANDE:0','')
r=r.replace(' ',',')
r=r.split(',')

camX=r[0]
camY=r[1]
camV=r[2]
print('R:',r)

print('X:',camX)
print('Y:',camY)
print('Vinkel:',camV)
```